# Navigation title text with text and string

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a login system on an app I am developing in Swift.

I have a label that uses:

```
self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString;
```

I want to have the navbar title work like: **Welcome, (Username)**

I currently have this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Welcome, ";
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just interpolate the username?

```
if let username = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Welcome, \(username)"
}
```

Comment: thanks that's great., additional question, this app links to a sql database and uses a unique code that shows data. how do i change the title of the screen that shows that data to be Code: 123(for example)

Comment: Sounds like you'll probably need to post another question with additional details about what you're looking to do with examples and such. There's not quite enough information in the comment for me to answer properly.